# Clarification about the Appendix to IEC 60559

Tags: c, language-lawyer, iso

C99/C11 mention several times the *Appendix to IEC 60559*. At first sight, it seems it would be *Annex F (IEC 60559 floating-point arithmetic)*, but it is somewhat confusing to see definitions such as this one:

> F.10.8.1 The copysign functions
>
> **copysign** is specified in the Appendix to IEC 60559.

First, there is a difference between *Annex* and *Appendix*, even though they are mostly synonyms. Is this relevant?

Secondly, if Annex F *is* such Appendix, why does it refer to itself in such a recursive manner, without giving the actual definition of function **copysign**? Shouldn't it say instead "**copysign** is specified in IEC 60559"?

Finally, I considered interpreting *Appendix to IEC 60559* as "an annex to the standard IEC 60559", that would be available in IEC 60559 itself (in the same way as Annex F is present in the C99/C11 standards), but I could not find it in the standard. The [preview](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:std:iso-iec-ieee:60559:ed-1:v1:en) available at ISO's website indicates only 2 annexes, *Annex A - Bibliography*, and *Annex B - Program debugging support*, which are both unrelated to the definitions mentioned in the C standards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C standard has an annex F. The IEC 60599 has an appendix.

`copysign` is mentioned in several places in throughout the C standard.
The C standards annex F discusses the entirety of the IEC 60559-1989 (with regard to the usage in C), which does include mention of `copysign`.

The date (i.e. 1989) of the IEC 60559 document is important here as the layout of the document is changed significantly in the current version that the ISO website is likely to be selling! Both C99 and C11 reference the 1989 version.

In annex F of the C standard the `copysign` function of IEC 60559 is specifically mentioned. Within that document (i.e. IEC 60559-1989), it is detailed within the appendix.

Thus:

> F.10.8.1 The copysign functions
>
> **copysign** is specified in the Appendix to IEC 60559.

is part of part 10 of the annex F of the C standard that tells you that `copysign` is specified within the appendix of IEC 60559.

Within the 1989 version of IEC 60559 (well actually I'm looking at IEEE 754-1985 but the layout should match the 1989 IEC document), `copysign` is mentioned in the section entitled "Appendix".
Within a more recent version of IEC 60559 (I have IEEE 754-2008 but the layout should match the 2011 IEC document), `copysign` is mentioned in sections 5.5.1, 6.3 and B.3

Comment: I do not have access to IEC 60559-1989, but I can see its [table of contents](https://webstore.iec.ch/p-preview/info_iec60559%7Bed2.0%7Db.img.pdf), and it does mention "Appendix A - Recommended functions and predicates", which contains (in IEEE 754-1985): "Copysign(*x*,*y*) returns *x* with the sign of *y*. Hence, abs(*x*) = copysign(*x*,1.0), even it [sic] *x* is NaN."  I thought that ISO would update the references to IEC 60559 in more recent versions of its standard, so I didn't consider looking for the exact 1985 version.

Comment: NB: Watch out for difference in publish dates between IEEE and IEC. Typically IEEE publish a standard (e.g. 754 in 1985) and some time later (e.g. in 1989) a working group of the IEC/ISO joint technical committee adopt it, and then publish it with their own name for it (e.g. ISO/IEC 6559). Thus IEEE 754-1985 and ISO/IEC 6559-1989 are *essentially* the same document, though the ISO/IEC sometimes reformat some things slightly in this process (in other standards, I've not noticed this with this particular one yet).

Comment: One noticeable change is addition of the ISO/IEC front matter (e.g. cover page and so on) and copyright information.